# COUNTIFS with Numeral comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not sure what mistake I doing with CountIFS.
Cells A1:A8 refer to cells in another sheet and B1 has the formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A8,">2020")
```

it gives 0
But same values are  hard typed in C1:C8 and D2 that references C1:C8 gives the right answer

Thanks

[image: Countifs]

Comment: You have numbers stored as text.

Comment: formatted  Column A to Number , still shows 0

Comment: [Change text to a number](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula that will work for either `Text` or `Numbers` in column **A**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(--A1:A8>2020)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works, But Why i am not able to use COUNTIFS ? for sake of continuity with rest of formula in my sheet , I want to use COUNTIFS